# Вызов функции через несколько секунд после прорисовки интерфейса java android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Есть один Activity и один xml в котором LinearLayout, в котором один TextView

Как можно вызвать функцию 
`public void createBtn () {Создает кнопку}`
 через несколько секунд после того как интерфейс прорисуетса и пользователь сможет прочитать TextView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OnGlobalLayoutListener()` то самое место где вы можете вызвать свою функцию. Это гарантирует, что ваша `View` полностью отрисована.

Вот пример:

```
textView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        // здесь вы можете сделать нужную задержку(например с помощью Handler().postDelayed()) и выполнить вашу фукнцию
        // здесь стоит отписать листенер, чтоб не вызывать этот метод всякий раз когда View будет перерисовываться 
        textView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
    }
});
```

Comment: Простите не могу понять что такое textView в вашем примере, и откуда он берется

Comment: Любой TextView. Здесь может быть любая View

Comment: ```TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.FirstTimeAct_tvText);``` - но я получаю ошибку в ```t.getViewTreeObserver()``` - (Cannot resolve symbol getViewTreeObserver)